# Unfamiliar with Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, raspberry-pi, gpio

Right now I have a Raspberry pi(B+) connected to a motor controller(L928n) that is manipulated by the gpio value. I am a beginner with python. The motor controller is controlling rc truck motors. "W" to go forward, "A" to go Left, "D" to go Right and "S" to Stop. The script is not working.. What did I do Wrong? Also can Tkinter determine when a key is being held down rather then pressed? Not sure if Tkinter is what I should be using for this type of project. Maybe pygame would work better?

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
import RPi.GPIO as gpio
import time
import sys
import Tkinter as tk 

def init():

   gpio.setmode(gpio.BOARD)
   gpio.setup(7, gpio.OUT)
   gpio.setup(11, gpio.OUT)
   gpio.setup(13, gpio.OUT)
   gpio.setup(15, gpio.OUT)
   gpio.setup(3, gpio.OUT)
   gpio.output(3, False)

def forward(tf):
    gpio.output(7, True)
    gpio.output(11, False)
    gpio.output(13, False)
    gpio.output(15, False)
    time.sleep(tf)
    gpio.cleanup

def stop(tf):
    gpio.output(7, False)
    gpio.output(11, False)
    gpio.output(13, False)
    gpio.output(15, False)
    time.sleep(tf) 
    gpio.cleanup()

def left(tf):
    gpio.output(7, True)
    gpio.output(11, False)
    gpio.output(13, False)
    gpio.output(15, False)
    time.sleep(tf)
    gpio.cleanup()

def right(tf):
    gpio.output(7, False)
    gpio.output(11, True)
    gpio.output(13, False)
    gpio.output(15, False)
    time.sleep(tf)
    gpio.cleanup()

def reverse(tf):
    gpio.output(7, False)
    gpio.output(11, True)
    gpio.output(13, False)
    gpio.output(15, False)
    time.sleep(tf)
    gpio.cleanup()          

def key_input(event):
    init()
    print 'Key:',event.char
    key_press = event.char

def key_press(event):
    init()
    key_press == event.char
    sleep_time = 0.030

if key_press == 'w':
    forward(sleep_time)
elif key_press == 's':
    stop(key_press)
elif key_press == 'a': 
    left()
elif key_press == 'd':
    right(sleep_time)
elif key_press == 'x':
    reverse(key_press)

command = tk.Tk()
command.bind('<KeyPress>', key_input)
command.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

The following block of statements:

```
if key_press == 'w':
    forward(sleep_time)
elif key_press == 's':
    stop(key_press)
elif key_press == 'a': 
    left()
elif key_press == 'd':
    right(sleep_time)
elif key_press == 'x':
    reverse(key_press)
```

is never executed because it is at the outermost level of indentation which is only read once (right after your function definitions). You need to indent it properly and include it in the appropriate `key_press` and `key_input` functions.

Edit:

```
def key_input(event):
    init()
    print 'Key:',event.char
    key_press = event.char
    checkKeyPress(key_press)

def key_press(event):
    init()
    key_press == event.char
    sleep_time = 0.030 
    checkKeyPress(key_press)

def checkKeyPress(key_press):
    if key_press == 'w':
        forward(sleep_time)
    elif key_press == 's':
        stop(key_press)
    elif key_press == 'a': 
        left()
    elif key_press == 'd':
        right(sleep_time)
    elif key_press == 'x':
        reverse(key_press)
```

I think your mistake is that you think that a function call to key_press() is some kind of `goto` - it's not. The function is called and after it ends, you jump exactly to the point in the code where you called it. You should also do some reading on variable scopes in python.

Comment: Thank you for time. What would normal indentation look like? Im a very visual learner... Could you correct the issue? That way ill remember it for next time.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by using something other than Tkinter...

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 
import RPi.GPIO as gpio
import time, sys

class _Getch:
    def __init__(self):
        try:
            self.impl = _GetchWindows()
        except ImportError:
            self.impl = _GetchUnix()

    def __call__(self): return self.impl()

class _GetchUnix:
    def __init__(self):
        import tty, sys

    def __call__(self):
        import sys, tty, termios
        fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
        old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
        try:
            tty.setraw(sys.stdin.fileno())
            ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
        finally:
            termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, old_settings)
        return ch

class _GetchWindows:
    def __init__(self):
        import msvcrt

    def __call__(self):
        import msvcrt
        return msvcrt.getch()

def Setup():
    gpio.setmode(gpio.BCM)

    #right
    gpio.setup(4, gpio.OUT)
    gpio.setup(17, gpio.OUT)
    gpio.setup(23, gpio.OUT)
    gpio.setup(24, gpio.OUT)
    gpio.setup(22, gpio.OUT)

    #right init are just "on"
    gpio.output(22, True)

    #left
    gpio.setup(12, gpio.OUT)
    gpio.setup(16, gpio.OUT)
    gpio.setup(18, gpio.OUT)


def QuitIt():
    sys.exit()

def getInput():
    got = int(raw_input('--> '))
    return got

# Right Forward gpio.output(15, True)
# Right Reverse gpio.output(13, True)

# Left  Forward gpio.output(18, True)
# Left  Reverse gpio.output(22, True)


def action(key):
    global delay
    if key == 'w':
        print "Forward"
        gpio.output(23, True)
        gpio.output(24, True)
        time.sleep(delay)
        gpio.output(23, False)
        gpio.output(24, False)

    if key == 's':
        print "Reverse"
        gpio.output(23, True)
        gpio.output(24, True)
        time.sleep(delay)
        gpio.output(23, False)
        gpio.output(24, False)

    if key == 'a':
        print "Left Pivot"
        gpio.output(4, False)
        gpio.output(17, True)
        time.sleep(delay)
        gpio.output(4, False)
        gpio.output(17, False)

    if key == 'd':
        print "Right Pivot"
        gpio.output(23, True)
        gpio.output(24, True)
        time.sleep(delay)
        gpio.output(23, False)
        gpio.output(24, False)

    if key == 'l':
        delay = delay + 0.1
        print ("Delay Up: " + str(delay))

    if key == 'k':
        delay = delay - 0.1
        print ("Delay Dw: " + str(delay))

    if key == 'q':
        print "Quit"
        QuitIt()

delay = 0.2

getch = _Getch()

Setup()

while True:
    action(getch())
```